# Tor Browser doesnt launch

Tags: browser, tor

I`ve tried 2 ways - install from Ubuntu Software and by:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo add-apt-repository universe
wget -q -O - https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring torbrowser-launcher
```

It is not launching. But after "terminal"-way installing after some minutes I see this window, that just stays and I have to cancel it:

[image]

if i start from terminal

```
torbrowser-launcher
```

[image]

and nothing happens

Comment: You haven't provided your release, and I'd recommend just using the default software package (which doesn't include the browser itself, just a stub which will download the browser).  Note if you've tried one method, in my experience you have to clean up & fully remove that method before another method will work (which may depend on releases or what was done - it's what I found anyway; so I've stuck to default package since and not had any issues).

Comment: what does it mean default software package?

Comment: I still don't know your release, but I mean https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=torbrowser-launcher&searchon=names

Comment: @guiverc 18.04 LTS is my version of Ubuntu

Comment: Tor Browser Launcher doesn't contain the Tor Browser code - it contains only the code to download and install the updated versions from Tor upstream.  There's multiple issues with the signature verification currently on 18.04 because of changed signing keys - no ETA on a fix for this in Bionic at this time.